# Other way to go from an activity to another activity instead of INTENT

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to go from an activity to other activity but withouth using Intents?? that's the way I'm using it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that I don't know why, but it takes too long to go from one activity to the other one.
Thanx you

Comment: How much time is "too long"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to go from an activity to other activity but withouth using Intents?

No.

> it takes too long to go from one activity to the other one

Use Traceview to determine where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way can navigate between activities without intents. Study activity life cycle, look for memory leaks. This should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in android is done by the intents.
And going from one activity to another activity is no exception.
So, intent is the only way to go from one activity to other..

Answer (score 0):

Check `onPause()` of first activity, see if you are doing some time taking work there? If so, optimise code. Or do the work in background thread.

Check `onCreate()`, `onResume()` etc. of second activity for time taking work. Use `thread/ handler/ asynctask` if required. Activity is not updated with UI till `onResume()`.